# Rails where query to find and then update BigDecimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

I need to update any records in my database where the amount attribute is of a given value. The amount attribute is saved as a `BigDecimal`.

Specifically my method to update an amount was incorrectly storing 14.97 as 149700 and 497 as 49700. So I have some correct 14.97 values and some 149700 values as well as some 497 values and 49700 values.

I need to find all records where the `BigDecimal` amount attribute, when converted to a float, would be 149700 and then update these records to 14.97 but store that as a `BigDecimal` and the same for 49700 to 4.97.

If the value was a float, I could just use:

```
Foobar.where(amount: 14.97)
```

But how do you find the amount where the `BigDecimal(:amount).to_f == 14.97`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) to search for records that match the criteria. I'd go with [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

`BigDecimal` has a [`to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-to_f) method so you can do something like:

```
users_to_update = User.all.select { |user| user.amount.is_a?(BigDecimal) && user.amount.to_f == 14.97 }
```

then there is a [`to_d`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/Float.html#method-i-to_d) method for `Float` so you can do:

```
users_to_update.each { |user| user.update_attributes(amount: 14.97.to_d) }
```